# Install grav localhost debian

Tags: php, apache, localhost, webserver, grav

I admit I'm not really a webmaster and I cannot run Grav on my localhost webserver.

I followed deeply the installation instructions, but I always end up with the same error page:

```
'mbstring' extension is not loaded. This is required for Grav to run correctly
```

Briefly these are the steps I made:

- downloaded and unzipped grav-admin
- copied the grav-admin folder in `/var/www/html`

All the dependencies should be installed, included the `mbstring`:

```
i  php-mbstring - MBSTRING module for PHP [default]
p  php-symfony-polyfill-mbstring - Symfony polyfill for the Mbstring extension
i  php7.3-mbstring - MBSTRING module for PHP
```

I also restarted Apache service a lot of times, but always the same error.

Grav runs with the php webserver, that is with `router.php`, but I really would like to run it with Apache.

BTW: other tools within `/var/www/html` are correctly handled and showed.

Comment: mbstring is part of PHP, but being you are on a unix is has to be installed specifically

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/491629/how-to-install-php-mbstring-extension-in-ubuntu

Comment: No @RiggsFolly, `php-mbstring` is ALREADY installed on my computer, see the text of the question and the output of aptitude. So it seems not to be an installation problem

Comment: Then the extension is not being added by the `php.ini` that you are using. Are you doing this from the command line?

Comment: yep from CLI. You mean `/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini`?

Comment: Well do a `>php --ini` to check which ini file is being used. Or just `>php -m` to see all loaded extensions

Comment: OK in `php -m`, `mbstring` is listed so should not be this problem. BUT doing `php --ini` I see that the `ini` file used is `Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php/7.3/cli`. While on `http://localhost/phpinfo.php` the version of php is `PHP Version 7.2.9-1`. Could it be this the problem?

Comment: Could well be a problem!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187939/discussion-between-matteo-and-riggsfolly).